# Xcode 6.0.1 mouse hover on variable pop up not display

Tags: mac, xcode, osx-yosemite

**OS version:** OS X Yosemite 10.10

**Xcode version:** Version 6.0.1 (6A317)

Specifically on Swift language when I place check points to debug code and variable runtime values. I'm not able to see the popover like wise in Objective C.

In Objective C when you debug code and hover mouse to any variable it shows pop over with run time value for that object.

For example:

[image]

But in Swift it won't show up.

1. Is it due to older Xcode version?
2. Do I have to change Xcode environment preference for that?
3. Is it bug from OS or from Xcode IDE?
4. Or Apple has disable this feature for security reason?
5. What is an alternative to see runtime value for local variable? Some time they don't even visible in debug area.

Comment: I wonder if this should be moved to stack overflow? He may get better answers there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bounty on this question was over still I did not got an answer, And I guess it is hard to get find the solution.

*Today I have found one Spotlight on this way*, it will not full fill what is asking for. How ever it is useful in the context.

From the tutorial of **[ios-8-visual-effects-tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/84043/ios-8-visual-effects-tutorial)**, I did found one note.

[image]

And you can see the variable value using step over like below image:

#### Select variable or view in console area and than hit space bar to view its information.

[image]